# TableLayoutPanel select cell in designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, tablelayoutpanel

I want to copy a label (red) and paste the control in a cell (blue) but it appears in another cell:

[image: copy and past here]

Results in:

[image: this is the wrong result]

How do I tell the designer in which cell I want the control pasted into?
I couldn't find any hints how to do that. The only thing that works as intended, if I drag a new control directly from the toolbox on to that cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. One may not be able to assign a control to a cell in the designer window, but in the *properties* window. If the control is a children of a `TableLayoutPanel`it gets a property called `Cell`:

[image: cell property in properties]

Change values accordingly.